# mysql: unknown variable 'table_definition_cache=400'

Tags: mysql, configuration, mac-os-x

I added lines to ~/.my.cnf which worked fine for weeks. Now I receive complaints when I run myqsl CLI.

System specs:

```
MAC OS X - El Capitan 10.11.13
```

Mysql Version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.29, for osx10.11 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Contents of ~/.my.cnf:

```
[client]
user = root
password = ***REDACTED***
host = 127.0.0.1

table_definition_cache = 400
table_open_cache = 400
```

These are the error messages I get when I type 'mysql' in bash:

> mysql: unknown variable 'table_definition_cache=400'
>
> mysql: unknown variable 'table_open_cache=400'

I only get the second error message if I comment out the first setting.

I needed these settings because otherwise I get these errors intermittently:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'sending authentication information', system error: 32
```

UPDATE:

This link suggested the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813630/mysql-5-6-headaches-on-mac-osx

I needed to put the settings in the [mysqld] section of the config file.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813630/mysql-5-6-headaches-on-mac-osx and https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71960

Comment: @NawazSohail - Thanks. The first link did the trick. I needed to put my settings in the [mysqld] section of the config file. Problem solved. If you post this as a solution, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this please put these configurations under [mysqld] section of config file. For reference check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813630/mysql-5-6-headaches-on-mac-osx)

```
[mysqld]
table_definition_cache = 400
table_open_cache = 400
```